# Deprecated: Return type of DirFilter::getChildren()

Tags: php, recursion

I am using a simple class for folder/file management. Normally running class gives deprecated error on some servers.

```
class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    protected $exclude;
    public function __construct($iterator, array $exclude)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->exclude = $exclude;
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        return !($this->isDir() && in_array($this->getFilename(), $this->exclude));
    }
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new DirFilter($this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->exclude);
    }
}
```

error output;

Deprecated: Return type of DirFilter::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveFilterIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveFilterIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

Deprecated: Return type of DirFilter::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

Is this method used not supported in some PHP versions?

Thanks

Folder and file listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is specified in the error code. change your code as below.

```
class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    protected $exclude;
    public function __construct($iterator, array $exclude)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->exclude = $exclude;
    }
    public function accept(): bool
    {
        return !($this->isDir() && in_array($this->getFilename(), $this->exclude));
    }
    public function getChildren(): ?\RecursiveFilterIterator
    {
        return new DirFilter($this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->exclude);
    }
}
```

extended RecursiveFilterIterator must be same structure with your old class. new version using getChildren(): ?\RecursiveFilterIterator and accept(): bool return types.

Comment: Please afd explanation why this is the answer. Not all readers are willing to do manual diff to see the change